# Сложение данных в angularjs

Tags: angularjs

Здравствуйте , не могли бы подсказать можно ли в angularjs складывать данные которые берутся из json?

Например: Есть Json из которого дергаются данные .
Можно ли сделать чтобы реквизиты складывались? , т.е. "B_3039" + "B_3036" и выводили общую сумму в таблицу

```js
var CupApp = angular.module('CupApp', []);
CupApp.controller('CupCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
  $scope.cups = [{
    "user": "Менеджер",
    "Total": 1715,
    "B_1011": 0,
    "B_1012": 0,
    "B_1013": 0,
    "B_1014": 0,
    "B_1015": 60,
    "B_1016": 0,
    "B_2021": 0,
    "B_2022": 60,
    "B_3031": 0,
    "B_3032": 0,
    "B_3033": 0,
    "B_3034": 0,
    "B_3035": 0,
    "B_3036": 0,
    "B_3039": 1595
  }];
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.7/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="CupApp" ng-controller="CupCtrl">
  <div id="container">

    <div id="Html1">
      <h2>Топ в компании</h2>
      <table class="table table-striped">
        <tr>
          <th>Менеджер</th>
          <th>Балы</th>
        </tr>
        <tr ng-repeat="cup in cups | orderBy: '-B_3039' ">
          <td>{{cup.user}}</td>
          <td>{{cup.B_3039}}</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: _Можно ли сделать чтобы реквизиты складывались? , т.е. "B_3039" + "B_3036" и выводили общую сумму в таблицу_ что за общая сумма? как это относится к разметке?

Comment: убери в сниппете запрос к несуществующему файлу и вставь напрямую массив

Comment: Нужно что бы из масива бралось несколько данных , например `"B_3039" + "B_3036"` и их сумма отображалась в таблице `<td>{{cup.B_3039}}</td>`

Comment: _и их сумма отображалась в таблице_ где именно в таблице? только этих двух полей?

Comment: `<td>{{cup.B_3036 + cup.B_3039}}</td>` попробуйте

Comment: Вместо поля `<td>{{cup.B_3039}}</td>`

Comment: _<td>{{cup.B_3036 + cup.B_3039}}</td> попробуйте_  Странно , пробовал не работало у меня)Судя по всему ошибся где-то . Спасибо , помогло